# Make pattern of asterisks and zeros in increasing lengths

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to echo stars and zero like the pattern below

```
*
***0
******00
**********000
```

The length of the asterisks grows by an increasing factor (in a ballooning fashion) -- the previous number of asterisks plus the current iteration number.

- iteration 1: 1 (0 + 1)
- iteration 2: 3 (1 + 2)
- iteration 3: 6 (3 + 3)
- iteration 4: 10 (6 + 4)
- iteration 5: 15 (10 + 5)
- etc

The length of the zeros increases by a static factor.

- iteration 1: 0
- iteration 2: 1
- iteration 3: 2
- iteration 4: 3
- iteration 5: 4
- etc

My code currently looks like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{   
    echo "*";
    for ($j=0; $j<$i; $j++)
    {   
       echo "*";
    }
    for ($z=0; $z<$i; $z++)
    {
        echo "0";
    }       
    echo "</br>";    
}
```

However I'm getting this result:

```
*
**0
***00
****000
*****0000
******00000
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? **There probably is a better way of doing it!**

Comment: does **********000 have 10 stars? if yes can you give us the pattern?

Comment: Homework? 1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4? How difficult can it be?

Comment: If you want to get a better grade with extra (y) use [PHP generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of stars is indicated by triangle numbers, `1`, `1+2`, `1+2+3`.  You want to increment your inner loop max value by `$i` with every iteration:

```
$k = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    $k += $i;
    for ($j=1; $j<=$k; $j++)
    {   
       echo "*";
    }
    ...
}
```

This is also a good case where your loops should be initialized with `1` rather than `0`, because it is more intuitive.  `0`-based loops work best when you are working with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is more efficient; you can cache the current sequence of stars and zeros.

```
$cache_star = "";
$cache_zero = "";
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    for ($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++)
    {   
       $cache_star .= "*";
    }
    echo $cache_star.$cache_zero;
    $cache_zero .= "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
for($i = 1; $i != 5; $i++)
{
    $triangle = (0.5 * $i) * ($i + 1);
    echo str_repeat('*', $triangle) . str_repeat('0', $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Uses the formula `0.5n(n + 1)` - the triangle numbers formula.

Example output:

```
*0
***00
******000
**********0000
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite like @jordandoyle's approach, but I correct the zeros pattern by subtracting 1 from `$i` in the second `str_replace()`..

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7tmmR))

```
$number = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; ++$i) {
    echo str_repeat('*', $i * .5 * ($i + 1))
         . str_repeat('0', $i - 1)
         . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
*
***0
******00
**********000
***************0000
```

---

If this answer lacks significant uniqueness versus an earlier answer, I'll include a recursive approach as well (instead of a classic loop).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/02pSu))

```
function printLines($i, $lines = [], $newline = PHP_EOL) {
    if ($i > 0) {
        array_unshift(
            $lines,
            str_repeat('*', $i * .5 * ($i + 1))
                . str_repeat('0', $i - 1)
        );
        printLines(--$i, $lines);
    } else {
        echo implode($newline, $lines);
    }
}

printLines(5);
```

---

You can even copy the previous line and insert it into the middle of the next line to form the desired pattern.  This is the functional-style equivalent of @CoertMetz's nested loop technique.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dD7LM))

```
$number = 5;
$line = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; ++$i) {
    echo (
             $line = str_repeat('*', $i)
                 . $line
                 . ($i > 1 ? '0' : '')
         )
         . PHP_EOL;
}
```

All above techniques deliver the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Smells like homework... But ok, what about this:

```
$star = "*";

echo $star."\n";

    for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
    {   
        $star = $star."**";
        echo $star;

        echo str_repeat("0", $i+1);

        echo "\n";    
    }
```

Outcome:

```
*
***0
*****00
*******000
*********0000
***********00000
*************000000
***************0000000
*****************00000000
*******************000000000
*********************0000000000
***********************00000000000
```

Demo:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/583644f782005adb9e018b965cbbdefaf63c7c79

Comment: his stars increase by more than 2 each time and the `0` increase