# Print pattern of increasing asterisks and zeros

Tags: php

How to print this Pattern?

[image: pattern]

```php
$number = 5;
for ($i=1; $i <= $number ; $i++) { 
    for ($j=$i; $j >= 1;$j--){
        echo "0";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
```

I've tries like this, but i'm confused to print star and Zero char

```php
for ($i=1; $i <= $number ; $i++) { 
    $sum = 0;
    for ($j=$i; $j >= 1;$j--){
        $sum +=$j;
    }
    echo $i ." => " .$sum ."\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1 => 1
2 => 3
3 => 6
4 => 10
5 => 15
```

Comment: I was unsure at first but this is near enough to be a duplicate of [Make pattern of asterisks and zeros in increasing lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71172533/2943403).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`str_repeat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat) to generate the strings of required length. Note that for triangular numbers `(1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...)` you can generate the `i`'th number as `i(i+1)/2`:

```
$number = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat('*', $i * ($i + 1) /2) . str_repeat('0', $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
*0
***00
******000
**********0000
***************00000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CvZHA)

For a more literal generation of the triangular part of the output (i.e. sum of the numbers from 1 to `i`), you could use this code which adds `$i` `*`'s and 1 `0` to the output on each iteration:

```
$line = '';
$number = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    $line = str_repeat('*', $i) . $line . '0';
    echo $line . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
*0
***00
******000
**********0000
***************00000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/76uCJ)

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is more portable #justsayin

Comment: @Phil funny... when I've used PHP_EOL in the past I've been criticised for over-complicating... but personally I agree with you and will update.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, which uses a more literal reading of the replacement logic.  Here, I form each subsequent line by taking the previous line, and adding the line number amount of `*` to the `*` section, and then just tag on a new trailing zero.

```
$line = "*0";
$max = 5;
$counter = 1;

do {
    echo $line . "\n";
    $line = preg_replace("/(\*+)/", "\\1" . str_repeat("*", ++$counter), $line) . "0";
} while ($counter <= $max);
```

This prints:

```
*0
***00
******000
**********0000
***************00000
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of zeros are equal to $i in the for loop. So we just need to calculate the number of stars and then simply do a str_repeat

```php
$count = 5;

for ($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++) {

  $stars = 0;
  for($j=1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
    $stars = $stars + $j;
  }

  echo str_repeat('*', $stars).str_repeat('0', $i)."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
*0
***00
******000
**********0000
***************00000
```

Comment: [`$stars = $stars + $j;` can be `$stars += $j;`](https://3v4l.org/jfIhe)

Answer (score 0):

```
$line = '';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

   $line = str_repeat('*', $i) . $line . '0'; // **str_repeat()** --> getting string length

   echo $line . PHP_EOL; // **PHP_EOL** ---> represents the endline character.

}
```